# Why does 'remove' mutate a list when called locally?

Tags: python, list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Understanding Python's call-by-object style of passing function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262920/understanding-pythons-call-by-object-style-of-passing-function-arguments)

I recently came across this:

```
x = [1,2,3]

def change_1(x):
    x = x.remove(x[0])
    return x
```

Which results in:

```
>>> change_1(x)
>>> x
[2, 3]
```

I find this behavior surprising, as I thought that whatever goes in inside a function has no effect on outside variables. Furthermore, I constructed an example where basically do the same thing but without using `remove`:

```
x = [1,2,3]

def change_2(x):
    x = x[1:]
    return x
```

Which results in:

```
>>> change_2(x)
[2, 3] # Also the output prints out here not sure why this is
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
```

And I get the result that I would expect, the function does not change x.

So it must be something `remove` specific that has effect. What is going on here?

Comment: This has been covered before: see [Understanding Python's call-by-object style of passing function arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10262920/understanding-pythons-call-by-object-style-of-passing-function-arguments).  Also see [the definitive treatment of the subject](http://effbot.org/zone/call-by-object.htm).

Comment: [Python tutorial 4.6](http://docs.python.org/release/2.7/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions), 6th paragraph (also look at the footnote). These things _are_ actually expained in tutorials.

Comment: What value do you think `x.remove(x[0])` returns?  What does it *actually* return?  What is the difference between mutating an object and rebinding and existing name to a newly created object?

Comment: Maybe, a good place for you to lookat some examples, and do some exercises to fully grasp how the language works is http://learnpythonthehardway.org/

Comment: It is clear Akavall understand local variables and the semantics of passing a list to a function. (Why is everyone assuming that he doesn't!). He's basically answered the question for himself: his suspicion is right: it is something specific to `remove`. `remove` is a destructive operation (it mutates the object). Slice extraction is not destructive; it computes a new list which is like the original, but with parts removed. That's it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the things that is confusing is that you've called lots of different things 'x'. For example:

```
def change_1(x):       # the x parameter is a reference to the global 'x' list
    x = x.remove(x[0]) # on the left, though, is a new 'x' that is local to the function
    return x           # the local x is returned

>>> x = [1, 2, 3]
>>> y = change_1(x)    # assign the return value to 'y'
>>> print y
None                   # this is None because x.remove() assigned None to the local 'x' inside the function
>>> print x
[2, 3]                 # but x.remove() modified the global x inside the function

def change_2(x):
    x = x[1:]          # again, x on left is local, it gets a copy of the slice, but the 'x' parameter is not changed
    return x           # return the slice (copy)

>>> x = [1, 2, 3] 
>>> y = change_2(x)
>>> print x
[1, 2, 3]             # the global 'x' is not changed!
>>> print y
[2, 3]                # but the slice created in the function is assigned to 'y'
```

Comment: Your prompt strings are on the wrong lines ;)

Answer (score 2):

You would get the same result if you called the parameter of your function `n`, or `q`.

It's not the variable name that's being affected. The `x` in the scope of your list and the `x` outside that scope are two different "labels". Since you passed the value that `x` was attached to, to `change_1()` however, they are both referring to the same object. When you do `x.remove()` on the object in the function, you are basically saying: "get the object that `x` refers to. Now remove an element from that object. This is very different than a lhs assignment. If you did `y=0; x=y` inside your function. Your not doing *anything* to the list object. You're basically just tearing the 'x' label of of `[1, 2. 3]` and putting it on whatever y is pointing to.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable x is just a reference to the list you've created. When you call that function, you are passing that reference by value. But in the function, you have a reference to the *same list* So when the function modifies it, it is modified at any scope.

Also, when executing commands in the interactive interpreter, python prints the return value, if it is not assigned to a variable.

Comment: Terminology quibble: it's not passed by reference; it's a reference type passed by value. Passing by reference would imply that you could assign another list to x inside the function and that the change would be reflected in the caller's scope.

Comment: Edited to reflect your comment. Thank you for that!

Comment: I'd argue that it's not passed by reference *or* passed by value -- Python uses what Liskov called "call by object sharing", which is a separate concept.  The key point is that Python *variables*, while bearing a superficial similarity, are not at all like variables in C-style languages.

Comment: I don't see how "call by object sharing" is different than passing a reference type by value (i.e. the value is a reference to object), but it's possible that I'm missing some subtlety. I'm also not sure how variables come into play here, since the variable `x` in the caller is a different variable than the `x` parameter in function. AFAIK, this all works the same as it does in, say, Ruby or C#.

Comment: @IsaacCambron: You're right, the difference is subtle at best.  I mainly prefer the "call by object sharing" terminology because it's more succinct than "call by value where the value is a reference" and less likely to get confused with "call by reference", which is a different concept where the word "reference" doesn't even mean the same thing. It's true, Python's model is pretty much the same as Ruby's, but be careful with comparisons to C#, since C# has some added wrinkles due to the dichotomy of value types and reference types.