# Pass-by-object-reference and mutability

Tags: python

Much has been written about python pass-by-object-reference. But it is confusing to read threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299427/python-functions-call-by-reference) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference).

In those threads, some say mutability is important, while others say that mutable or immutable objects are handled the same way.

I have a simple question, why are the contents of `a` not modified in the first snippet of code and modified in the second? According to [this explanation](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/) of pass-by-object-reference, shouldn't the contents of the reference be modified in both cases?

```
def fn(b):
    b += 1
a = 2
fn(a)
print(a)

def fn(b):
     b += [4]
a = [2]
fn(a)
print(a)
```

Comment: The posts (not threads; SO is not a forum) that you link to contain huge amounts of information. Please read through the available answers instead of asking us to reprint them.

Comment: Technically, Python uses "[call by sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing)," an obscure term. Also, your confusion really stems from a fundamental misunderstanding of Python variables. Variables in Python are like name tags that we place on objects. When we pass an an argument to a function, we put the name tag given by the parameter on that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> shouldn't the contents of the reference be modified in both cases?

No, since `int` objects are immutable.

You don't even need functions to demonstrate this.

Consider the following:

```
a = 1
print(id(a))
a += 1
print(id(a))
>> 496418832
   496418848
```

We are obviously getting a new object.

Compare to:

```
a = [1]
print(id(a))
a += [2]
print(id(a))
>> 36641608
   36641608
```

Note `a` is still referencing the same object in this case.

Comment: Your usage of `id` really clarified things for me. Thanks!