# Function changing variables outside of the function (that is not Returned by the function)

Tags: python-3.x

First off really sorry for the nondescript title, I don't know how to phrase my question.

Given the code below:

```
x = [9]
y = [2,4,6]

def f(x, y):
    if len(x) > 0:
        z = x + y
        x.pop(-1)
    return z.pop(0)

print(f(x,y)
print(f(x,y))
```

The second print line gives me an **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'z' referenced before assignment**

I understand what this error is, as the function is skipping the if clause and going straight to the return z.pop(0), but z doesn't exist because z is defined in the if clause.

**What I would like to know is why the value of x is changed by the function**
The function skips the if loop because after the first call, x has been changed from x = [9] to x = []

I thought that unless it is a Return statement, then any variables changed or created within a function are **local to the function?**

For example, [geeksforgeeks.org](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/global-local-variables-python/) states that

> Any variable which is changed or created inside of a function is local, if it hasn’t been declared as a global variable

So why is the value of x changing when it hasn't been returned by the function? Shouldn't the value of x always be [9]?

Thank you

Comment: You are never creating an `x` in the function (`x=...`) so `x.pop()` mutates the global `x`.

Comment: but I am changing x though? Like the quote from geektsforgeeks.org says.
So doesn't that mean it stays local?

Comment: The quote is wrong... mutating changes (on mutable types), e.g. `x.pop()` does not create a local `x`. Assignment creates a local variable.

Answer (score 1):

Lists are mutable. When you pass one into the function then you are really passing in a pointer to the list. It's better to think of Python as pass by reference than pass by value. The x you are changing is not created in the function it is passed in as an argument. You're not changing x (the memory address pointed to by the label x), you're changing the contents of that memory address.
See this answer [Python functions call by reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13299427/python-functions-call-by-reference)