# Python function can modify list or dict outside but not string

Tags: python

Why Python function can modify `list` or `dict` but not a `string` outside:

this makes sense, because function create scope, so the setit function create new variable:

```
ttt = 'ttt'

def setit(it):
    ttt = it
    print(ttt)

def showit():
    print(ttt)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setit("lsdfjlsjdf")
    showit()
```

But how to explain this, the setit function can modify the list outside:

```
aaa = []

def setit(it):
    ttt = it
    aaa.append(it)

def showit():
    print(aaa)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    setit(123)
    showit()
    setit(234)
    showit()
```

Answer (score 4):

Because **strings are immutable**. You cannot edit strings, you can just create new strings.

Source: [Python Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#why-are-python-strings-immutable)

See also: [Function calls in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33066581/562769)

Comment: No hesitation answering an obvious dupe! Nice!

Comment: but use global can change it?