# Why is my function overwriting a variable, when it's theoretically not supposed to? (Python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, overwrite

### A function is overwitting a variable which is given it as an argument. Why?

What is this whole code supposed to do:

- create a list (main deck) of objects representing cards
- create an empty list for storage od the ids of cards already drawn from the main deck
- choose randomly 5 cards from the main deck and add them to the list (player's deck)
- return temp list of ints (ids of cards in the main deck) to a variable
- add items from the temp list to the main list

  ```
      import random

      from common import cards

      deck = cards.deck()  # creates a list of 52 class objects representing cards


      def main():
          used_cards_ids = []  # this one is being overwritten in the next step, according to the debugger

          players_deck, temp_used_cards_ids = generate_players_deck(used_cards_ids)  # this is the "next step"
          used_cards_ids.extend(temp_used_cards_ids)  # adds id of the cards which were drawn from the main deck

          print(used_cards_ids)  # prints a double list of cards ids (i.e 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5)


      def generate_players_deck(temp_used_cards_ids):
          players_deck = []
          counter = 0

          while counter < 5:  # until 5 cards were drawn
              cards_id = random.randint(0, 51)  # chooses a random card
              if cards_id not in temp_used_cards_ids:  # checks if the card with the same id weren't previously drawn
                  counter += 1
                  temp_used_cards_ids.append(cards_id)  # adds card's id to the list of drawn cards
                  players_deck.append(deck[cards_id])  # adds card to the player's deck
              else:
                  continue

          return players_deck, temp_used_cards_ids  # returns player's deck (list of cards objects) and list of ids of the drawn cards


      main()
  ```

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what the issue is?  What variable is it overwriting that you don't expect?

Comment: If you mean it's overwriting `used_cards_ids`, as I'm guessing from the description of your question, it appends data to it in the function when you pass in `used_cards_ids`. Then you extend it afterwards with itself, because you return it as the `temp_used_cards_ids` argument.

Comment: Are you under the impression that functions get copies of all their arguments? They don't. Python isn't a pass-by-value language.

Comment: Primitive types (e.g. int, str, NOT list) are passed by value, but nothing else. Technically python is a pass by object-reference language (https://stackoverflow.com/a/33066581/6685140)

Comment: @user1558604 "used_cards_ids" this one. At the point when python prints it, the result is twice the number of given ids. It seems like at this point: "used_cards_ids.extend(temp_used_cards_ids)" the "used_cards_ids" is already filled with some characters, although IMO it should be empty.

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb Yes! Yes it does this very thing. But why does it do that? I can't get it. At which moment does it "append data to it in the function when you pass in "used_cards_ids""?

Comment: @user1558604 No, the other comments did not anwser my question, but actually dddJewelsbbb got the closest to it. I know python does the exact thing dddJewelsbbb written, but I can't get why.

Comment: Take a look at this for the differnce between deep and shallow copy. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246693/what-is-the-difference-between-shallow-copy-deepcopy-and-normal-assignment-oper/17246744#17246744

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass in `used_cards_ids` to `generate_players_deck()`, you are providing the body of `generate_players_deck()` to `append` data to `used_cards_ids`, which you've *aliased* to `temp_used_cards_ids`.

You then get the value back from the `return` statement of that function, which you store in the variable `temp_used_cards_ids`, and then you `extend` that `temp_used_cards_ids`, which is actually `used_cards_ids`, essentially altering the list you passed in twice.

When you pass a list as a function argument, you aren't passing the *values* of the list, you're passing a *reference to the original list.* That's probably where your confusion is coming from, or perhaps the switch between variable names and function argument aliasing.

Comment: Thank you! I did not know it.