# How does list(arr) works in recusion python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = len(graph)-1
        
def dfs(graph, i, part, res):
    part.append(i)
    
    if i==n:
        res.append(part)
        return 
    
    for j in graph[i]:
        index = len(part)
        dfs(graph, j, list(part), res)
        # part = part[:index]
            
if __name__ == "__main__":
    res = []
    part = []
    graph = [[1,2],[3],[3],[]]
```

Earlier I was using `part = part[:index]`, as in python list is always passed as reference and thus value gets updated. But, then I came across `list(part)`, it actually removes the appended values in last recursive call, and works as expected.

Can someone explain what actually happens here?

Comment: "as in python list is always passed as reference and thus value gets updated." no, nothing is *ever* passed by reference in Python. In any case, `list(part)` creates a copy of the list that was being referenced by `part`

Comment: Maybe look into ```copy``` module.  To answer your question, list() returns a new object.  So, if you pass a Python list to a ```list(my_list)``` the returned value with be a copy of the original.

Comment: "no, nothing is ever passed by reference in Python." can you explain your claim?
As when you pass a list in python and keep on appending values, it actually updates the original list.

Comment: If you call `help(list)`, then you will see that `list` is a class.  And by `list(part)` you are creating a new list object.  The argument of `list` is assumed to be iterable (not necessarily a list object), perhaps internally the values of the given iterable are pushed into the new object sequentially.

Comment: And be aware that the behavior is similar to the shallow copy.  For example, `x = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]; y = list(x); y[0][0] = 9; x` gets `[[9, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`. The original x is updated.

Comment: @KotaMori can you give an example for the above solution when this shallow copy can create problem?

Comment: @nolanding yes, that doesn't imply pass by reference. In pass by reference, suppose you define a function `def foo(&x): x = 0`. Here we using imaginary syntax `&x` in our parameter to indicate the parameter that is being passed by reference. [This mirrors the C++ syntax for pass by reference, which is an example of language that actually supports it](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.4.0?topic=calls-pass-by-reference-c-only). So when you do `y = 42; foo(y); print(y)` it will print `0` because assignments to the parameter in pass by reference *are seen by the caller*.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I guess this answer helps. 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/33066581/8747223.

Comment: @nolanding yes that is a good answer, but one quibble is that there aren't just 3 evaluation strategies, there are many.