# python Modifying slice of list in function

Tags: python, list, slice

Consider the following piece of code:

```
def func1(a):
    a[:] = [x**2 for x in a]

a = range(10)
print a  #prints [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
func1(a[:5])
print a  #also prints [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

I wish to send a slice of the list `a` and change it inside the function. My expected output is

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Which way is the idiomatic way to do so?

Thanks!

Comment: You can also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054698/python-modifying-list-inside-a-function

Comment: @Kasramvd As the other question has no slicing, I do not believe that these are duplicates. Thanks for the reference anyway...

Comment: That's a trivial difference, but the main problem is that changing a mutable object inside a function may reflect the caller.

Comment: @Kasramvd I disagree. I peeked on that question *before* I wrote mine, but was not sure what is the _pythonic_ way to deal with slices in these cases.

Comment: @Kasramvd FYI I reopened, because the former dupe link was just related. I'm letting you know because I hate when someone reopens behind my back, but here I think it should be done.

Answer (score 6):

If you slice the list, you modify only a copy, so what you want to do doesn't work in the form you want.

But you could pass an optional `slice` object to `func1` and if it's not `None`, use it to perform the slice assignment (else use `[:]`)

I would do the following (used a `lambda` to avoid copy/paste of the formula and a generator expression to avoid creating a useless temporary list:

```
def func1(a,the_slice=None):
    e = lambda y : (x**2 for x in y)
    if the_slice:
        a[the_slice] = e(a[the_slice])
    else:
        a[:] = e(a)
```

testing:

```
a = list(range(10))
func1(a)
print(a)
a = list(range(10))
func1(a,slice(5))   # stop at 5
print(a)
a = list(range(10))
func1(a,slice(5,len(a),2))  # start at 5 / stop at the end, stride/step 2
print(a)
```

result:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 25, 6, 49, 8, 81]
```

- in the first case, the totality of the list was changed
- in the second case, it only changed the first half.
- in the third case, it changed the second half, but 1 value out of 2 (stride=2)

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
a = range(10)

a[:5] = [c**2 for c in a[:5]]
```

Comment: thanks, I presented this toy example as a mean of expressing my bigger issue, hence this straightforward answer doesn't really help...

Answer (score 0):

`a[:5]` creates a new list. Hence, the changes that `func1` applies to it are not mirrorred in `a`. You could add the slicing to the function:

```
def func1(a, start=None, stop=None, step=None):
    start = start if start is not None else 0
    stop = stop if stop is not None else len(a)
    step = step if step is not None else 1
    a[start:stop:step] = [x**2 for x in a[start:stop:step]]

func1(a, stop=5)
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to execute this idea without messing it with indices?

Comment: You can assign to a slice, but that doesn't change the fact that `fnc1(a[:5])` passes a list to `fnc1` that knows nothing about the original `a`.