# Why the list doesn't change?

Tags: python

I'm trying to add a value in a ordered list but the list won't change:

```
def insert(V, x):

    if len(V)!=0:

        for i in range( 0 , len(V)-1):
            if (V[i]<=x)and(V[i+1]>=x):
                V=V[0:i+1]+[x]+V[i+1:len(V)]
                print("\nExpected: \n"+ repr(V))
                return

    V=V+[x]
    return
```

i have this:

```
V=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
insert(V, 6)
print("\nResult: \n"+ repr(V))enter code here
```

and this is the result:

```
Expected: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

Result: 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I can solve the problem setting V as the return but I want the function to work on the list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python; modifying list inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054698/python-modifying-list-inside-a-function)

Comment: Is there a reason you can’t use `list.insert()`?

Comment: ```v.insert(index, value)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing can be done simply with `list.insert`.

As to why your function does not work, you need to update the original list using a *full-slice* assignment, so that the list passed to the function is updated via the current reference `V`:

```
...
V[:] = V[0:i+1] + [x] + V[i+1:len(V)]
# ^
```

Note that the RHS (Right Hand Side) is a new list object. Assigning to `V` alone rebinds the name/variable to a new list object. However, using a slice assignment ensures the original list is updated with values from the new list.

Comment: i know that i have more simple way to do it, but i'm studying for another course and i take this opportunity for revise python ;)
[i'm sure that i have make some wrong in the sentence]

Comment: mmm i don't know what rhs means :P

Comment: @Lorenzo Updated :)

Comment: RHS means "right-hand side." In the case of `x = y`, `y` is the right-hand side of the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You could just append your value to the list and sort it afterwards

l.append(value)

l.sort()

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't change `V` in place.

```
V=V[0:i+1]+[x]+V[i+1:len(V)]
```

After this line, `V` is no longer a reference to the list that was passed to the function, but another list. This line doesn't change the first list, but creates a new one.

You must `return V` and then get the result OR call a method on `V`, for instance `list.insert()`.

Answer (score -1):

As others have pointed out, you're not modifying the original list. (Instead, you're creating a new list and then not returning it.)

Here's a solution that takes advantage of `list.insert` to modify the existing list:

```
def insert(lst, value):
    '''Insert a value into a sorted list in-place, while maintaining sort order'''

    for i, x in enumerate(lst):
        if x > value:
            lst.insert(i, value)
            return

    # fallback, in case this is the new largest
    lst.append(value)

a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
insert(a, 6)
print(a)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

**EDIT**

More compact but probably harder to read:

```
def insert(lst, value):
    lst.insert(next((i for i, x in enumerate(lst) if x > value), len(lst)), value)
```