# Making a globally available list

Tags: python

I want to access a list which is field from different python function. Please refer below code for more details

```
abc = []
name = "apple,orange"
def foo(name):
   abc = name.split(',')
   print abc

foo(name)
print abc
print name
```

The output is as below.

> ['apple', 'orange']
>
> []
>
> apple,orange

Since I am new to python can anybody explain me why the 7th line (`print abc`) doesn't give the result as ['apple', 'orange']?

If I need to have the filled list at the line 7 (['apple', 'orange']), what should I do ?

Comment: Because, outside your function, `abc` is still an empty list...

Comment: thanks.. what should I do to have the filed list?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Short Description of the Scoping Rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules)

Comment: add the line `global abc` within your `foo()` function if you want it to modify the global abc variable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python; modifying list inside a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22054698/python-modifying-list-inside-a-function)

Comment: This will make your programs more difficult to understand. Why do you need to have it global? Just return the list and assign it to a new name if needed.

Answer (score 2):

```
abc = []
name = "apple,orange"
def foo(name):
   global abc # do this
   abc = name.split(',')
   print abc

foo(name)
print abc
print name
```

Answer (score 2):

While other answers suggest to use `global abc`, it is considered (in general) to be bad practice to use global variables. See [why are global variables evil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158339/why-are-global-variables-evil)

A better way would be to `return` the variable:

```
name = "apple,orange"
def foo(name):
   abc = name.split(',')
   return abc

abc = foo(name)
print abc
print name
```

Answer (score 0):

abc from function is not the same as abc from first line, because abc in def foo is a local variable, if you want to refer to abc declared above you have to use global abc.